# Reloading apache kills running FastCGI php scripts

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

i am using apache 2.4 with php as fpm. Whenever i reload apache (graceful restart), a running php script is getting killed. The user then sees an error 500 and the following is getting logged:

```
Connection reset by peer: [client xx.xx.xx.xx:52240] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" aborted: read failed

FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
```

Is there a way to reload apache without "disturbing" running php processes?

Comment: If those php processes are run on fastcgi and not cli, I'm afraid no. The apache has a open connection and when you restart apache, the connection gets closed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! Actually those php processes do run as fastcgi ...